# Monte Carlo Simulation using uniformly distributed random numbers

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I have written a program to calculate the definite integral of a function (say sin(x)) using the Monte Carlo method. However, I think the way I am using the mt19937 is not right, or there is another problem in the code since it does not return an expected result.

Here's my code:

```
    mt19937 RandomEngine(0);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> RandomDouble(0.0,1.0);
    double x = RandomDouble(RandomEngine);
    int NumberOfSimulations;
    cin >> NumberOfSimulations;
    double SumOfValues=0;
    for (int iSimulation = 0; iSimulation < (NumberOfSimulations -1 ); iSimulation++)
    {
        SumOfValues += sin(x);
    }
    SumOfValues /= NumberOfSimulations;
    cout << "The integral's result is: " << SumOfValues << endl;
```

Can you please tell me why the output is not even close you accurate?

Comment: When asking what is wrong with existing code, provide a [mre], including a complete program (show the `#include` statements, definition of `main`, and everything else needed to compile and run), sample input that demonstrates the problem, observed output, and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your program takes one random sample, in `double x = RandomDouble(RandomEngine);`, and then adds its sine repeatedly.

You need to take a random sample in each iteration. Move `double x = RandomDouble(RandomEngine);` into the loop.

Additionally, `for (int iSimulation = 0; iSimulation < (NumberOfSimulations -1 ); iSimulation++)` appears to use the wrong bound. You sum `NumberOfSimulations-1` samples but then divide by `NumberOfSimulations`.